# Dealing with a mix of Arrays and ES6 Iterators

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequence, iterable

So I'm coming to javascript from Python, and I'm experiencing some friction when it comes to operating on sequences.

In python, something like `reduce` is a global function that takes any kind of sequence. This is great, as I don't need to change my code depending on whether the value I'm working on is a list or a generator.

In javascript, `reduce` is a method of `Array`.

Particularly when using things like `Map`s I'm often working with an `Iterator` rather than an `Array`.

My initial thought was, "aha! I should probably be using lodash, I'm sure those functions don't care what kind of Iterable I have". Turns out lodash expects to be given `Arrays`, so doesn't help me!

Are my struggles indicative of doing something that's not idiomatic javascript? Or is the whole `Iterator` side of javascript still a bit immature?

Should I just be normalising all `Iterators` to `Arrays`? Or am I right to be wanting to keep things as `Iterators`?

Comment: You can convert iterators to arrays using `Array.from` or `[...iterator]`. Could you provide some iterator examples?

Comment: If you have a `Map` present, then you can always use `Object.keys(yourDict).map( key => { logic } )`, or `Object.values(yourDict).map( (value => { logic } )` or event `Object.entries(yourDict).map( ( [key, value]) => { logic } )`.

Comment: You might consider using RxJS and its operators ([reduce in particular](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce)), which is quite type-friendly. And yes, if you don't really care about asyncs, you can always transform an iterator to an array.

Comment: There is [a proposal for iterable helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) but unfortunately, it's not ready yet. It does seem like what you're looking for. Right now you're looking for some functions like `map<T, U>(it: Iterable<T>, fn: (x: T) => U)` that take an iterable an act on it. You can write them yourself easily.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is not a plain object. It has its own [`.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), [`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), and [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) methods that return iterators.

Comment: _"Looking for some guidance. Is there a popular library I should be using that is TypeScript friendly that will solve all my problems?"_ - That's off-topic for SO.

Comment: @VLAZ that proposal totally sums up what I'm struggling with, and the "prior art" section looks like this might have some useful pointers towards solutions.. thanks!

Comment: _"Are my struggles indicative of doing something that's not idiomatic javascript? Or is the whole Iterator side of javascript still a bit immature? Should I be looking to plug the gap with some 3rd party library to get closer to the Python state of affairs?"_ - Now you're asking for opinions which is also off-topic...

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: `Array.from`

```js
Array.from(iterator).reduce
```

Method 2: Spread

```js
[...iterator].reduce
```

Method 3: write some global helper functions

```js
const map = (func,iterator) => {
    let result = [];
    for (let value of iterator) {
        result.push(func(value))
    }
    return result;
}

const reduce = (func,iterator,init) => {
    // I'm not about to write my own reduce implementation here
    return [...iterator].reduce(func,init);
}
```

Then you can be closer to python